# Reference data when MapPolygon is clicked

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I plot a bunch of `MapPolygons` and set a `Tapped` listener for when one is clicked

```
polygon.Tapped += polygon_Tapped;
```

but when that gets called how do I know what one was tapped so I can display data associated with it?

For example in a `Pushpin` I could set data in the `.Tag` but that is not available for a polygon. I see that in the `TappedRoutedEventArgs` there is an `OriginalSource` object which would give me a reference to the object that raised the event but I still wont be able to associate data with that polygon.

the only thing I can think of is using a `Dictionary` to keep a reference to the object and check if the object equals the object clicked in a loop.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post on this last week. You can find it here: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2014/01/23/make-clickable-shapes-in-the-native-bing-maps-control.aspx

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887)  and add enough detail to your answer to make it not completely reliant on an external link.

Comment: In this case the answer is best answered with a link that contains a full detailed answer. Posting the 3 or 4 page response on a forum like this isn't really a good practice. Also, this link adds validation to the quality of the answer as it's a Microsoft blog showing how to answer a question about a Microsoft product.